# Touchscreen triggered by cheek while on the phone?

Tags: calls, touchscreen

When I'm on the phone, my cheek will often push buttons on the screen, causing either the call to end, or unintended navigation. This is really annoying - I try my best to keep my face away from the phone but I'm not always successful.

Am I the only person having this problem?
Is there an actual solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Droid there's actually a proximity sensor that disables the screen if anything is too close to it.  On the Droid this sensor is up next to the ear speaker so that when you put the phone up to your ear it triggers the proximity sensor.

What model phone do you have?

Comment: For what it's worth, I also have a Droid, and sometimes the proximity sensor doesn't quite work. It's entirely possible that I'm holding the phone in a way they didn't anticipate, or I just have a funny head.

Comment: I have an HTC Aria.

Comment: @Marcel Lamothe - The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Aria) for your phone lists a proximity sensor as a hardware input, so I'd try to find out why that isn't working.  It might be set to a sensitivity that you aren't triggering if you don't put it right against your head.

Comment: Yep, just tried it out - now that I know the phone has a proximity sensor (didn't even occur to me before) and where it is (in the top right corner), I had no problems at all - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On my phone I can click the power button to turn off the screen, so no buttons are there to be pressed.

Comment: Nice, just gave it a try and it worked like a champ, thanks!

Comment: On my phone the power button is the end call button.

Comment: @amanda this is a setting in the accessibility menu: http://imgur.com/8VggX